# What does 'TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list' mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've tried EVERYTHING and my teacher is unhelpful sos

```
print("Input a list of data into the function: median([d1, d2,d3, ...])")

def median(data):
    data = sorted(data)
    center = int(len(data)/2.0)
    if len(data)%2.0==0:
        return print("Your median is", str([(len(data))/2.0])+([((len(data)/2.0)+1)/2] +"."))
    else:
        return print("Your median is", str(data[center]) +".")
```

I need to calculate the median.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you seem to be concatenating a `str` to a `list`. Use a debugger to step through your code to examine it in detail.

Comment: `str([(len(data))/2.0])` you seem to be forgetting to index something. Maybe `str(data[(len(data))/2.0])`? Also indexing with a float `(len(data))/2.0` will raise a TypeError. You'll need to make it an integer first.

Answer (score 1):

Problem:

```
# s => string
# l => list

str([(len(data))/2.0]) + ( [((len(data)/2.0)+1)/2] + "." )
# ssssssssssssssssssss + ( lllllllllllllllllllllll + sss )
```

The `+` operator is overloaded to add string to string or list to list:

```
print('Hello ' + 'World') # 'Hello World'
print( [1] + [2]) # [1,2]
```

It does not understand list + string- hence error.

---

You almost got your solution. You can make it better by using floor division and reuse the already calculated `center` - this makes `if len(data)%2.0 == 0:` far easier to understand:

```
def median(data):
    ll = len(data)
    if ll == 0:
        return ""
    data = sorted(data)
    center = ll//2    # use floor div to get an integer
    if ll%2.0 == 0:
        med = (data[center-1] + data[center])/2.0 
    else:
        med = data[center]
    return "Your median is {}.".format(med)
```

Test:

```
for l in [[1], [1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5]]:
    print(l,median(l)) )
```

Output:

```
[1] Your median is 1.
[1, 2] Your median is 1.5.
[1, 2, 3] Your median is 2.
[1, 2, 3, 4] Your median is 2.5.
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] Your median is 3.
```